# Creating a bash script by calling a command file that contains only linux commands. But it fails with error "command not found"

Tags: linux, bash

For simplicity I removed all command and just using one command "ip addr"

```
admin@danec>cat commandfile.txt

ip addr

admin@danec> cat script.sh

IFS=$'\n'

COMMAND=/tmp/commandfile.txt

for command in `cat $COMMAND`
do
{
   echo $command
   $command
}
done

admin@danec>./script.sh

ip addr
./script.sh: line 7: ip addr: command not found
```

There is no issue of path because when I copy the command "ip addr" in separate script file and execute, it works fine.

Comment: It looks like its trying to find “ip addr” i.e. ip<space>addr

Comment: Can't you run the `commandfile.txt` as a script? `script.sh` seems to be a wrapper around it anyway.

Comment: Reading lines with `for` and storing commands in variables are [both](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) [problematic](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Rather than trying to fix this code, I'd recommend dumping it and using a different approach (like `source` or `.`).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

readarray -t commands < /tmp/commandfile.txt

for cmd in "${commands[@]}"; do
    echo "$cmd"
    eval "$cmd" || break
done
```

The error you had is caused by `IFS` being set to `$'\n'` which prevent word splitting from splitting command arguments.  Better rely on `readarray` and explicit `eval` since that's what you want to do.

As for whether this is safe, it's another topic.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the context is, but maybe just

```
. /tmp/commandfile.txt
```

?

If you really need the commands echo'd back,

```
set -v; . /tmp/commandfile.txt; set +v
```

Comment: There's the echo too but I agree maybe he doesn't really need it.

Answer (score 0):

Like @konsolebox mentioned, the issue is due to your `IFS` variable. When wordsplitting occcurs, it only wordsplits between newlines. This means that when you try to do `$command`, it doesn't see `ip addr` as two words: only 1 word (as below)

```sh
$ "ip addr"
bash: ip addr: command not found
```

To solve this without using `eval`, you can simply set the `IFS` to the default value *after* you do `$(cat "$COMMAND")`. Of course, a more elegant solution would be using indexed arrays and the `readarray` builtin, but if it is for something quick, the below solution works just fine

```sh
IFS=$'\n'

COMMAND=/tmp/commandfile.txt

for command in $(cat "$COMMAND"); do
   IFS=$' \t\n'
   echo $command
   $command
done
```

And also, a little tip, you don't have to use cat if you construct the for loop as such:

```sh
for command in $(<"$COMMAND"); do
```

Comment: This is ok if commands are made up of plain simple arguments but it will inhibit redirections and many forms of expansions.